# read csv-file as dataframe with python and skip first sign as column

Tags: dataframe, element, skip

I have a question concerning reading a csv-file with python. The csv file contains a easy table.
My approach was using read_csv:

```
infile="xyz.csv"
data = pd.read_csv(infile, sep='\s+')
```

The problem is, before the first column "column_1" was a sign "#"
The problem is, that he took the sign "#" as the first column of the dataframe.
Thus the last column named "column_3" just included "NaN"
Can you maybe give me a hint, how I can skip/ignore the first element "#", so that the first 
columns is "column_1"? I hope you can help me.
[This is a picture of how the content of the csv file looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGLp6.jpg)

Best wishes to you

Comment: Can you share, how your dataframe or csv file looks like

Comment: thank you for you answer. I have added a picture, how the content in csv-file looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Your csv file is wrongly formatted, is this what your `df` looks like?

```
    #   column1     column2     column3
0   2         3           4         NaN
1   4         5           6         NaN
```

Try loading your dataframe like this,

```
pd.read_csv(infile, names = ['column1', 'column2', 'column3'], skiprows = [0])
```